# Sharepoint 2010 on a Sharepoint 2013 farm? Beneficial?

Tags: 2010, development, 2013, search, farm

Here is an article that shows how to present SharePoint 2010 on a SharePoint 2013 farm: http://nikpatel.net/2012/10/13/understanding-sharepoint-2010-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/

If I do the process of having a SharePoint 2010 on a SharePoint 2013 farm, will I get the search benefits SharePoint 2013 has? Or any of the SharePoint 2013 features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the search benefits right away, you won't get some of the UI components until the visual upgrade is done. I remember being in a BA Insight presentation a couple months ago where they talked about upgrading to get the backend services like search but stay on the 2010 UI until ready.